# Plesk Site Preview redirects to Plesk Login

Tags: redirects, authentication, plesk

I moved over an existing PHP site to Plesk Panel 11.5 and now I'm having an issue with the site preview.

When I click site preview the site comes up fine in a new window, however when I try to navigate within site I'm redirected to the Plesk Panel login on the the new window.  Then if I click on the Plesk Panel window, I'm also redirected to plesk panel login.

How can I make changes to site and preview them without having Plesk site preview redirect me to Plesk login?

Comment: Is you issue only within the Preview or when you actually go to the website, using your domain, it does it also? I am a bit confused with the wording of your issue.

Comment: Only within preview for now.  I haven't setup domain to actually go to website.  This is my first time setting up site on plesk and I figured I could make all changes using preview, then when I finished worry about setting up domain.